# What software can I use for simple 2d graphics for Mac in c#, c++ or python?

Tags: python, c++, c#, graphic-design

I have a project where I need to do simple 2d graphics like ellipses, sectors, flood fill and etc. I've been working on Visual Studio Windows Forms c# with my old PC. It would be much more convenient for me to work on my Mac but Visual Studio for it doesn't support Windows forms.
Now I need a recommendation on software that supports 2d graphics in c#, c++ or python.
Thank you in advance.